dvips can't find pk-fonts in TeX Live
I have to re-translate an old TeX source code that was written 30 years ago for LaTeX 2.09 and used bm2font to integrate images via special pk fonts. After a few adjustments, this works so far. Only when I try to use dvips to translate the dvi file into Postscript are the pk character sets, which of course I still have (as well as the associated tfm files), not found. I've already tried to make the paths known using the DVIPSFONTS environment variable, but it doesn't work. Does anyone have a good tip for me? I'm using Tex Live on Kubuntu 24.04.

welcome! where are the files in relation to the working directory? have you tried just dropping them all in the same directory as you .tex file?

are the pk files the resolution that dvips is expecting? (texlive is looking for dpi600/xxx.pk by default

on windows the fonts are stored in folders named by mode (e.g. ljfour) and the files are named as cmr10.600pk, so you should check what your system is doing.

Yes, I tried dropping them into the same directory. Originally the fonts are in /usr/local/share/texmf/fonts/pk/laserjet/300dpi. /usr/local/share/texmf is the local texmf-directory of my system. The fonts are 300dpi, so I used the variable \pdfpkresolution=300. But dvipdf also cannot find the fonts.

I wouldn't expect dvips to use pdfpkresolution, try dvips -D 300 file.

Trying to use the "-D" option I got the following error: kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 300 --mag 1+0/300 --dpi 300 teila mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for teila. mktexpk: perhaps teila is missing from the map file. kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log. dvips: PK font teila not found; using cmr10 </usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/pk/ljfour/public/cm/dpi600/cmr10.pk> dvips: Design size mismatch in font teila
I have no map file for the fonts, only tfm and pk (in the example teila.tfm and teila.pk).

as you did the fonts into the laserjet folder, you could try to add that as mode dvips -mode laserjet -D 300

Now I get the following error: kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode laserjet --bdpi 300 --mag 1+0/300 --dpi 300 teila mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for teila. mktexpk: perhaps teila is missing from the map file. kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log. dvips: PK font teila not found; characters will be left blank. The system tries to recreate the fonts instead of using the existing ones.

run a document which uses bitmap, e.g. \documentclass{article} \usepackage{phonetic} \begin{document} \pc{abc} \end{document} and check where it places the pk fonts (and how it names them) and put yours at the side of them (you can use pdflatex, it will use the wrong mode, but show you the fonts and their path on the end of the log).

not being in the map file is fine, by the way. latex doesn't know whether there should be a type1 font or only bitmap, so this is a clue if you expected it to find the former. bitmap/pk fonts don't go in the map files.

Thanks to Ulrike Fischer! After observing that pdflatex writes new fonts to subdirectories of ~/.texlive2023/texmf-var/fonts/pk/ljfour/public and names the font-files according to the scheme "fontname.600pk" I copied my old files to a new subdirectory in this path and renamed them to "fontname.300pk". Then pdflatex uses them and I got a PDF of the 30 years old TeX-code using \pdfpkresolution=300 in the preamble.
